# Adding a Second Hard Drive to a Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

I am thinking about installing a second hard drive into my ubuntu server. How hard is it to do this bearing in mind that it's a server and has no GUI. Also is there some way to merge the 2 hard drives together (without buying a raid card etc)?

Just want to see how hard it would be before i buy anything. Thanks

Comment: Adding the drive is easy, you just update fstab as described here.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive  Posting as comment because I can't answer the part of your question about RAID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux kernel supports software RAID (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) or even Logical Volume Management (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) without any cards or extra hardware.

It depends what sort of RAID you want to implement, but basically the steps are:

1. install the new drive, and create a new, degraded array (that is only the second disk without the first one)
2. copy all contents needed from the first disk to the new array,
3. make all necessary changes to boot from the new array,
4. reboot,
5. verify if everything goes smoothly,
6. add the old disk to the array (which destroys the original system, hence the importance of the verification in step 5.)

If you want to implement RAID-0 take care that you need a separate boot partition (/boot) which must be RAID-1 (or no RAID at all).

Comment: So can i add a new HDD without having to reinstall the whole system? I litterally want to add another one and link them both together to have more space if that makes sense

Comment: You certainly can do this.  However, putting two disks in RAID-0 is rarely a really good idea (especially in a server system): if _any_ of the disks is faulty, you can loose **all** your data.